# coc-tsserver nvim indenta con tabs en lugar de espacios

Tags: vim

Estoy usando `coc.nvim` y `coc-tsserver` como como servidor de lenguaje para javascript, todo esta trabajando perfectamente, excepto la indentacion, cuando inserto una nueva linea o cuando formateo el texto con `:call CocAction('format')` se indenta con tabs y yo preferiría que fuera con 2 espacios, como puedo cambiar esta funcionalidad?

Comment: Hola guzajj, estás en el sitio de Stack Overflow en español, por favor traduce tu pregunta.